# ag-grid datetime issue, making time 00:00:00

Tags: html, css, typescript, ag-grid, angular9

After Choosing date and time from angular material datepicker when I sent it to ag-grid setFilterModel() it just makes the time 00:00:00.

This is what I am sending to ag-grid setFilterModel():

```
timeStamp:
dateFrom: "2021-04-20 10-00-00"
dateTo: "2021-04-21 23-04-27"
filterType: "date"
type: "inRange"
```

ag-grid then automatically changes the timestamp in query:

```
dateFrom: "2021-04-20 00:00:00"
dateTo: "2021-04-21 00:00:00"
filterType: "date"
type: "inRange"
```

Is this a bug in ag-grid.

Answer (score 0):

Ag Grid doesn't support custom date formats at the moment.

Try providing your date separating the time fields with `:` (ie. `2021-04-20 10:00:00`).

That should fix your problem. If the dates come like this from a database, you can use the `valueGetter` property to replace `-` with `:`